# Vlookup from closed file in VBA Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that in few rows needs to VLOOKUP a value in a separate file that is closed.

I have come up with the code:

```
     temp = Left(Cells(row, 5), 10)
     temp2 = "VLOOKUP(" & temp & ";'F:\folder\[file.xlsx]Worksheet1'!$A:$B;2;0)"

     Cells(row, 7).Formula = temp2
     Cells(row, 7).Replace "VLOOKUP", "=VLOOKUP"
```

IT does vlookup fine, but only for the frist row - if I put it into the loop, then all other rows are getting "formula error" msg box.

Comment: try this, and tell who it works: Cells(row, 7).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Left(" & Cells(row, 5).Address & "; 10);'F:\folder\[file.xlsx]Worksheet1'!$A:$B;2;0)"

Comment: It returns error 1004 on the only way around it I've foundhe statement you've provided. I tried it before and the only method around it I was able to find was the one I got above but it only works for first row

Comment: What kind of data are you looking up - text or numbers?

Comment: The value I am using to search is a number and the return value is text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now I remember i had similar problem. In VBA code in formulas you must use comma instead of semicolon:

```
Cells(row, 7).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Left(" & Cells(row, 5).Address & ", 10), 'F:\folder[file.xlsx]Worksheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"
```

Comment: Turns out i got some misspellings - fixed it and error 1004 disappeared

Now it nicely adds formulas to rows - but every cell displays "#NAME?" errors - once I manually go into a cell and execute the formula it works nicely

Comment: Ok got it - it turns out that using LEFT function it considers it a TEXT not number - using VALUE command fixed it :)

Thanks a lot! You totally helped me!